# Update formulas in Excel by increments of 1 when copy/pasting with several cells in between

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking to make work easier for myself by copy/pasting Excel formulas. This is usually no issue for me, but on this particular worksheet, there are several cells in between what I'm pasting.

What Excel is doing:

Taking formula
`=IF(SolData!B40 = "[VACANT]", "MTOE SLOT NOT ASSIGNED", SolData!B40)`
from A1 and pasting it in A10 gives me
`=IF(SolData!B50 = "[VACANT]", "MTOE SLOT NOT ASSIGNED", SolData!B50)`

What I want to do:

Take formula
`=IF(SolData!B40 = "[VACANT]", "MTOE SLOT NOT ASSIGNED", SolData!B40)`
from A1 and paste it in A10 giving me
`=IF(SolData!B41 = "[VACANT]", "MTOE SLOT NOT ASSIGNED", SolData!B41)`

Any insight? I'm not an Excel noob, but I'm no guru either.

What it is going in for some visual: [SolWorkbookScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz5Oi.png)

Comment: Are you populating the format shown in the image, or pulling data from the format shown in the image? Either way, please add a second image showing the data on the other sheet.

Comment: My workaround is to copy and paste to A2, then drag A2 to A10.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement some logic to your formula, e.g., (assuming the number of rows between referenced cells are uniform)...

`=IF(INDIRECT("SolData!B", ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/10))) = "[VACANT]", "MTOE SLOT NOT ASSIGNED", INDIRECT("SolData!B", ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/10))`

I'm not at my computer at the moment to check, but something like that should work if the rows are offset uniformly.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. The example I gave was bad because I didn't even count the example I was given, but the offset was 15. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: No problem!  If you found my answer to be helpful, I'd be much obliged if you might consider giving it an upvote or selecting it as the answer, at your discretion of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is inaccurate, because when you copy from A1 to A10, the offset will be 9, so the address in the reference will change from B40 to B49 and not to B50.
So I'm assuming you're copying from A1 to A11 so that the offset is 10.
In order to obtain a shift of 1 in such a case, you need to calculate these shifts and use the  INDIRECT function, for example, like this:
(to shorten the notation I marked the texts "X" and "Y")

```
=IF(INDIRECT("SolData!B"&40+INT((ROW()-1)/10)) = "X", "Y", INDIRECT("SolData!B"&40+INT((ROW()-1)/10)))
```

In this formula column `B` is fixed and the starting row number 40 as well.